# Vertex with two labes (label in, weight out)

Tags: diagrams, tikz-trees

I use the `tikzpicture` environment to make graphs. I would like to make a vetex in the graph with comondo `\Vertex` with an internal value to the vertex (label's vertex) and another value outside (weight's vertex). I know there is a command LabelOut can do one or the other, but both is not possible. Is there any solution to my problem? Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities: the first one uses the `LabelOut` key and then `\node` to place the label inside the node; in the second one, the labels are inside (default), and again a \node is used to place the labels outside (using the `<name>.angle` syntax);

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}

\tikzset{VertexStyle/.style={
  shape=circle,
  shading=ball,
  ball color=cyan!50,
  minimum size=18pt}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\SetGraphUnit{3}
\SetUpVertex[Lpos=-60,LabelOut]
\Vertex{A}\EA(A){B}
\node at (A) {a};
\node at (B) {b};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\SetGraphUnit{3}
\Vertex{a}\EA(a){b}
\node[below right] at (a.-60) {A};
\node[below right] at (b.-60) {B};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @WellingtonPreviero You're welcome! Don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the checkmark to its left. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).